# How to check and return a message if no value entered

Tags: javascript, function, dom, input

I'm still learning and am trying to simply take a number from an input, add 7 to it, and then display it on the webpage. It all works fine, but what I don't like is if you hit "submit" without entering a number, the HTML field shows "NaN" vs. a custom message, which is what I'd like to do.

Here's the code I have so far. What am I missing to capture that nothing was entered and return a different message?

```js
function add7() {
  let number = document.getElementById('num').value;
  let addition = 7;
  if (isNaN(number)){
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML ="Please enter a value";
  }
  else { 
    let original = parseInt(number,10);
    num = addition + original;
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = num;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  Add 7 to the number <br>
  <input type="number" id="num">
  <button onclick="add7()">Press Button</button>
  <hr>
  <p id="add"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because [an empty string actually returns true when passed to `isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Examples), i.e. `isNaN('')` returns `true`.

To do that, you can simply move the check to the final step, a.k.a. evaluate the `num` variable instead:

```js
function add7() {
  let number = document.getElementById('num').value;
  let addition = 7;
  let original = parseInt(number, 10);
  let num = addition + original;
  
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = num;

}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  Add 7 to the number <br>
  <input type="number" id="num">
  <button onclick="add7()">Press Button</button>
  <hr>
  <p id="add">
  </p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can also simply parse the input element's value directly: it will inform you if it is not a number right away:

```js
function add7() {
  let number = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value, 10);
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
    return;
  }
  
  let addition = 7;
  let num = addition + number;
  document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = num;

}
```

```html
<div class="add">
  Add 7 to the number <br>
  <input type="number" id="num">
  <button onclick="add7()">Press Button</button>
  <hr>
  <p id="add">
  </p>
</div>
```